# MongoDB - update a field inside a map entry

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

We have a mongodb document with the following structure: One of the document's fields is a map, and each map entry has several fields of it's own.

We want a way to update the value of **one field** inside a **specific map entry** using mogodb update query.

To clarify things, if we have the document as bellow, we want to update "callBackUrl" for entry 1 in the map "urlSettings" to "yadayada.com".
Is that possible at all?

```
SystemSettings : {

   urlSettings : {

      1 : {
         callBackUrl : "blabla.com",
         (more fields...)
      },

      2 : {
         ...
      },
      ...
   },
   ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

check the below query :

```
 db.collection.update(
   {"SystemSettings.urlSettings.1.callBackUrl" : "blabla.com"},
   {"$set":{"SystemSettings.urlSettings.1.callBackUrl" : "yadayada.com"}}
 );
```

Comment: Ok, sorry, upon second look - it doesn't work, the old value is still there

Comment: I didnt get you... can you explain in breif, wat modifications you are trying ?

Comment: I tried what you said, and it didn't change the values (please ignore my earlier response...)